# Python built-in function for exponential weighting with half-life parameter

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

In Python, is there a built-in function that achieves the following, perhaps with better performance?

```
def exponential_weights(n, halflife):
    """Generate weights with length=`n` that decays exponentially for distant elements.

    Output weights are sorted from old to new. So output[0] is the most distant weight and output[-1] is the newest.

    """
    return np.array([.5**((n-ii-1)/(halflife-1)) for ii in range(0, n)])
```

Comment: You can vectorize: `return 0.5**((n-np.arange(n)-1)/(halflife-1))`

Comment: Nice. About 10x faster for `n=10000`.

Comment: Glad it helped, however does it really make sense to compute this over 10k points? The ratio between the first and last item will be in the order of magnitude of 2**n, which for n=10000 is much much greater than numbers that can be handled in numpy.

Comment: No the real use cases usually have `n` in the hundreds and `halflife` also in low hundreds.  For example n=260 and halflife=130.  260 stands for 260 weekdays in a year, and 130 is 6 months.