# Pandas rolling-apply to calculate correlations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rolling-computation

This question is linked to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628358/python-built-in-function-for-exponential-weighting-with-half-life-parameter?noredirect=1#comment135104793_76628358).

I want to calculate rolling exponentially-weighted correlation between two columns in a pandas Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_obs = 10000
window = 260
min_obs = 130
halflife = 130

# create a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n_obs, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

# initialize weights
w = 0.5**((window-np.arange(window)-1)/(halflife-1))

# correlation for a single sliding window. 
# note because of `min_obs`, df_win might be of various lengths
def _corr_single_window_(df_win):
    return df_win.mul(w[-df_win.shape[0]:], axis=0).corr().iloc[0, 1]

# test on the dummy dataframe
df.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_obs).apply(_corr_single_window_)
```

And I got this error:

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: What are the contents of `df`?

Comment: The obvious question: Does your dataframe contain numeric data? See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to include a sample of your input so that we can better understand your question

Comment: I intended to show the creation of the dummy dataframe but forgot to write `df = ...`. Edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you receive this error is because `df_win` is actually a `pd.Series`.  The `.rolling.apply` does not pass a `pd.DataFrame`, so the correlation calculation is not possible - as there is only a single series of data.  There is more of an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617218/18571565).

Here are a few options for computing the correlation in your question:

### Option 1 - rolling apply

Using almost the same code as yours, I have adapted this to instead use the global variable `df` at the start of the return code, so that both columns are used, rather than the single column in `df_win` (as this is a `pd.Series`.  Also, I have changed the line calling the function to only run for a single column, else the output is returned twice.

```py
def _corr_single_window_(df_win):
    return df.loc[df_win.index].mul(w[-df_win.shape[0]:], axis=0).corr().iloc[0, 1]

df.rolling(window=window, min_periods=min_obs)["A"].apply(_corr_single_window_)

# 18.2 s ± 437 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Option 2 - list comprehension

This list comprehension computes has an if else statement for the `min_obs`, and uses `max(0, i-window)` as the lower bound in `.iloc` so that this increases from the start of `min_obs` to the full `window` length.  If you are using `Python>=3.8` then you can use a ["walrus operator"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) within to not repeat this calculation.

```py
pd.Series([df.iloc[max(0, i-window): i]
           .mul(w[-(i-max(0, i-window)):], axis=0)
           .corr().iloc[0, 1]
           if i>=min_obs
           else np.nan
           for i in range(1, len(df) + 1)])
# 12.8 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# (or with walrus operators for Python >= 3.8)
pd.Series([df.iloc[(min_idx := max(0, i-window)): i]
           .mul(w[-(i-min_idx):], axis=0)
           .corr().iloc[0, 1]
           if i>=min_obs
           else np.nan
           for i in range(1, len(df)+1)])


# 12.8 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Option 3 - with rolling pipe

Mostly adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991897/18571565), this uses `.pipe` to chain functions together.

```py
def rolling_pipe(dataframe, window, fctn):
    return pd.Series([dataframe.iloc[max(0, i-window): i].pipe(fctn) 
                      if i >= window else None 
                      for i in range(1, len(dataframe)+1)],
                     index = dataframe.index) 

df.pipe(rolling_pipe, window,
        lambda x: x.mul(w[-x.shape[0]:], axis=0).corr().iloc[0, 1])

# 7.66 s ± 1.9 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As can be seen in the timings above, the third option is most efficient.  However, given the large number of observations only 7 runs were made and testing multiple times gave quite varied timings.

Comment: I understand all three options, but to me Option 1 is most readable. I now get the feeling that `.rolling().apply()` is too generalized and too strict at the same time. There must be a more elegant AND efficient way of doing rolling-on-dataframe-and-output-single-value-for-each-window!